# How do you deal with escaping special characters in vim?

Tags: vim, find-replace

I am trying to search and replace one `TTL` (which is short for "title") with another `TTL` like below...

```
:%s/TTL:"\$\\sqrt{s} =  14\$ TeV"/TTL:"<S1B>, \$\\sqrt{s}\$ = 14 TeV/gc
```

to change the line below

```
TTL:"$\sqrt{s} = 14$ TeV"
```

into

```
TTL:"<S1B>, $\sqrt{s}$ = 14 TeV, <LUM> = 300 <IFB>",
```

Basically, when I try to search and replace `TTL:"$\sqrt{s} 14$ TeV` vim tells me that it can not find the pattern I was searching for. Do I need to include some character to like a backslash or something to help vim find it?

Comment: it's sure your text doesn't have that pattern!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!, where is the '=' in your regular exp. And you have to escape the special chars of vim.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks. Oops

Comment: Kris, how do I escape the special chars of vim?
I got this after putting the equal sign there
https://gyazo.com/516716816f5b9cc10fb58abb3fa7e92a

Comment: What does Perl have to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%s/TTL:"\$\\sqrt{s} = 14\$ TeV"/TTL:"<SIB>, \$\\sqrt{s}\$ = 14 TeV, <LUM> = 300
 <IFB>"/g
```

Comment: tried it - didnt work, https://gyazo.com/10e96286a4b3df60c3960cf7c9e2709c

Comment: please poste your text in your question, not the img.

Comment: I'm working in a virtual machine its just easier for me with gyazo but ok

Comment: just copy the text in the vim editer and paste in your question.

Comment: yeah, i copy it in my vim and use the script, it works.

Comment: is there a way I can make sure vim is finding the pattern before I try to replace it?
Could I do it with a forward slash? would I still have to include the backslashes?

Comment: if this you have to do your homework.

Comment: Well I looked and found search and it only works when you include the backslash but for some reason when I go to replace it and I include the backslash for the special characters it still tells me the pattern isn't found :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125257/discussion-between-kris-roofe-and-kebur-fantahun).